# 2D data stored in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, 2d

This question is about SQL.

Students data (names, birthday ...) are stored in a first table (STUDENTS). Assessments data (date, time, teacher ...) are stored in a second table (ASSESSMENTS).

Now, I want to store the answers of each student to each assessment. Should I create a new table (ANSWERS for example) that store each answer for each students with two keys (one linked to STUDENTS and the other linked to ASSESSMENTS) ? Is it the best practice ? If yes, I worry about performances with a large number of students and assessments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The use of what you call `ANSWERS` -- and what I would call `StudentAssessments` -- is the right way to store this information in a relational database.

This is called a junction table in SQL and it is the standard way of implementing n-m relationships.

Some databases have alternative methods of storing lists within a field -- nested tables, JSON, arrays, XML.  However, these generally do no fit the relational model very well.  For instance, foreign key references often cannot be defined and enforced.

I would not worry about a "large" amount of data.  What you consider to be big, is probably pretty small by database standards.